# progress bar for playing videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I'm trying to add a progress bar that shows how far a videos into it's duration, but one that can be placed outside the video itself(like on another part of the screen). I've been looking around for some time, and have only found ones for showing the loading progress, which is what I don't need. Can anyone help me find where to find that, or supply one themselves even.

just in case it's needed, here's the script for the video

```
var numb = $(this).index(),
            videos = ['images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v'
            ],
            myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
            myVideo.src = videos[numb];

            myVideo.load();


    setTimeout(function(){

        myVideo.play();
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could bind an event listener to the `timeupdate` event:

```
myVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
   // if the video is loaded and duration is known
   if(!isNaN(this.duration)) {
        var percent_complete = this.currentTime / this.duration;
        // use percent_complete to draw a progress bar
    }
});
```

Pick a max length for your progress bar, multiply it by `percent_complete` (which is between 0 and 1), and use that product as the current length of the bar.